# Form does not get Submitted via Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, scrape

```
URL = 'http://public.dep.state.ma.us/SearchableSites2/Search_UST.aspx'
agent = Mechanize.new()
agent.get(URL)

form = agent.page.form_with(:action=>/Search_UST.aspx/)
form.submit(form.button_with(:value=>'Search'))

puts agent.page.body
```

The above snippet is suppose to submit the form and receives search results page. However, the form does not get submitted. Instead of getting results page, I get the form page as if I did not submit the form.

That's the source page I'm trying submit http://public.dep.state.ma.us/SearchableSites2/Search_UST.aspx

Any suggestion on how to overcome this problem?

Thank you

Comment: ASP forms tend to have additional data to be sent along the request. Inspect what's being submitted and add those fields into your Mechanize code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that Search button has a "doPostBack" action in the `onclick`. So you will need to parse that and do something with it.

Comment: Can you elaborate please. Thanks

Comment: Sure, there's some javascript happening in the onclick, you need to emulate that or switch to something that does javascript like watir-webdriver

Comment: Watir fits well. Cheers